# How to upgrade to python 3.6.4 on macos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm trying to use python 3.6.4:

```
n155-p250:Desktop sahandzarrinkoub$ brew upgrade python3
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
bash-preexec        jenkins             presto              ttf2eot
cppcheck            khard               qpdf                txr
docker-gen          lz4                 scummvm             unixodbc
duplicity           mdp                 scummvm-tools       verilator
get-flash-videos    mycli               sslsplit
get_iplayer         ola                 tin
gobuster            ponyc               tokei

Error: python3 3.6.4_2 already installed
n155-p250:Desktop sahandzarrinkoub$ python3
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5926, Jul 16 2017, 20:11:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Even though I already have it installed, I can't use it by typing `python3`. How do I solve this? I want to remove 3.6.2 and have `python3` map to 3.6.4.

Comment: what is the output of `which -a python3`?

Comment: It's /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: then what is the output of `ls -al \`which python3\``

Comment: `n155-p250:Desktop sahandzarrinkoub$ ls -al 'which python3'
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  69 Sep 11 17:37 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `python3` is not linked to homebrew one, you should let homebrew force relink `python3`:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/python3
brew unlink python3; brew link --overwrite python3
```

link of `python3` on my machine is:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.6.4/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 1):

To update python run `brew update` in the Terminal (this will update Homebrew) 
Then `brew upgrade python3` 
At the end you can run `brew cleanup python3` to remove the older version

Comment: Sorry, same problem remains